# Apart from losing €40, is there any further risk if someone has my prepaid credit card number and home address?

Tags: credit-card, phishing, scam

My girl was scammed and entered my home address and my credit card number on a fake website (through a Facebook ad). What risks am I additionally incurring, apart from having lost €40 (the money that was on the card, and luckily that is one of the cards that you have to charge in advance to make a purchase)? Is there something especially urgent I have to do?

**My card description:**

- Can only pay what I first charge in
- Do not allow to transfer money to my bank account
- I choosen that card to lose at most the money is in it (Even if my bank insisted I choose instead another type of card).

Comment: What does "you have to charge in advance to make some buy" mean in the context of a credit card?

Comment: @Michael I believe he is referring to a prepaid credit card

Comment: You should also take this chance to help educate her on internet security, and probably install an ad blocker so that things like this won't happen in the future :)

Comment: It's more about identity theft than just money. Imagine if this card (which you associated with yourself when making purchases and/or reloading it) was used for criminal activities like money laundering or buying phones for terrorists. You don't want to be involved in such an investigation even if you are innocent.

Comment: I'm not sure about Europe, but in America, prepaid cards are not typically referred to as "credit cards." At least not when the difference actually matters in context (which it does here). They're just called "prepaid cards" or "gift cards." "Credit card" usually implies an actual line of credit behind it. Even a card that's attached to a bank account instead of a credit line is differentiated as a "debit card" or "bank card."

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what kind of "preload credit card" that is? A debit card? Or other bank card, as @jpmc26 asked? Or some of the new "wireless payment cards"?

Comment: @jpmc26 In my part of the world (Australia), anything with a Visa, MasterCard, or American Express (et. al.) logo is generally referred to as a "credit card" regardless of whether or not there's actually an attached line of credit. Contrast this with an [EFTPOS](https://www.eftposaustralia.com.au/) card, which can be used at ATMs or points-of-sale but not anywhere a credit card is accepted. (They're not called "bank cards" because Bankcard was a brand of credit card.)

Comment: @Marcel It's probably something like a [prepaid MasterCard](https://www.mastercard.com.au/en-au/consumers/find-card-products/prepaid-cards.html). Some of these are only good for the original amount; others may be topped-up again and again, then discarded when no longer required (or expired).

Comment: @Calrion We don't know that for sure, hence Marcel's request for clarification.

Comment: @Marcel that's a card that I can use only with money that I charge in it and has no information on "where to transfer money on my bank account". I would add "LUCKILY" (and my bank insisted I would use the other type of card which is "more risky").

Comment: @DarioOO : stolen prepaid card was one the method chosen by the terrorist of Paris attacks. Though not reaching that religious point, be prepared to get you card used for criminal activities and the police to use this as the unique evidence they found that your the author of those crimes.

Answer (score 48):

Call the credit card company! They have procedures for this including blocking your credit card and replacing it. You might even be able to get the 40€ back.
There is a lot of articles about this [online](http://lifehacker.com/what-should-i-do-if-my-credit-card-gets-hacked-1552850022).

If you knowingly ignore the issue you might be liable for any future damages by fraudulent credit card charges.

Comment: I'm more concerned about legal implications (what if they make an order of illegal stuff and send that to my home?), yes 40€ is a lot money, but not money that change life. Thanks for your input anyway! Thanks for having edited your answer.

Comment: What kind of legal implications do you mean? i only read now that it is a card that requires charging in advance. If you charge it again they might just use it again. No point in keeping it :) i don't know what you mean about legal implications but if so than you should ask your question on http://law.stackexchange.com/ After the edit on your comment. if you just call and report it you're not responsible and they will help you fix the problem.

Comment: maybe the OP is worried that the scammer can use the money for some illegal purchases which might later be tracable back to the OP

Comment: @user13267 I understood that after he edited his question. It doesn't change the solution though. Call the credit card company :) If he knows about it but willingly ignores the issue then yes he might get into trouble at some point. (I'm now law expert but i can imagine.) There is no reason to just not call the credit card company and be done with it and have ease of mind.

Comment: @DarioOO Reporting the thing to the credit card company is the first remedy for that too. If something does get traced back to you through the credit card, it's good if you can back up the "card details were stolen" claim with the fact you reported it to the credit card company. There might be more you can do (I don't know) but that's the first thing you should do.

Comment: @Jasper Exactly, always good to have some kind of evidence speaking for you instead of just talk. PS: Your comment confused me for well over a minute because of the similar nickname and the fact that Jasper is my first name. ;') First I thought I accidentally posted another comment just quick scanning the pop-up.

Comment: Umm..  This is a **pre-paid** card that comes pre-loaded with money or you can do it yourself.  It's little more than a gift card and doesn't have any links with a bank account.  If someone stole the card, all they'd have is 40 euros.

Comment: @Pete Where did you get that information? He is talking about a pre-paid creditcard. Most likely he means a pre-paid mastercard. which is likely linked to his name. Even if he can't recharge it, if he wants to be sure about not being linked to any illegal activity concerning it, the urgent thing to do is still call the company that provided him the card. A gift card is not on anyone's name.

Answer (score 28):

### What additional risks are there?

1. The hacker could attempt to use the credit card number for other purchases
2. The hacker could attempt to use your address and credit card information to impersonate you.  For example, if you bank web site has a "forgot my password" feature that asks you to enter your credit card number.
3. The hacker, if local (not likely), could visit your home address, and can try to get into your mailbox or trash to steal any other credit cards, PIN mailers, or other personal information.

### What should I do?

1. Contact your bank to report the incident.  They may recommend issuing a different card, or placing limits on the current card (e.g. bar it from use in certain countries).  They can also set up alerts on the card so they can notify law enforcement when and where it is used next.
2. Monitor your statements for other improper charges and report them in a timely fashion.
3. Ask the bank for a [chargeback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chargeback), which will allow you to fully recover your 40€ immediately.  This is usually a pretty painless process.
4. Always, always use a locked mailbox, and always shred any sensitive documents before putting them in the trash or recycling.

Comment: Much of this answer wouldn't apply to the prepaid "credit" card that the original poster has. There's no more money left on the card thief to steal. The card wouldn't be connected to any bank account, nor would there be any statements mailed. Disputing charges made with prepaid cards is more difficult than with ordinary credit cards.

Comment: Think it depends on the card.  The most popular cards in the US, and all cards with the "Visa Clear Prepaid" logo, are in fact FDIC insured and regulated, provide monthly statements and online access, etc.  But you're right, there are less reputable and feature-rich cards out there as well.

Comment: Hackers have called up Amazon and added a new credit card. Then, they called up Amazon again and used their knowledge of that credit card on the account to get access to the account. Even if the card doesn't have money on it, this could be an attack vector. Though, now that I think about it, almost any card would do, so not sure it's specific to this situation.

Answer (score 11):

It heavily depends on what exists in the contract you signed with the bank and in which country you live - some banks protect the customer more than others...

In any case, *as you know the card number has been compromised* you should immediately call the bank. Failure to do so could be classed as serious *negligence* and subsequent actions by the attacker could be argued as your responsibility.

If you do report it, depending on your country and your contract, part or all of the expenses could also be recovered.

Answer (score 5):

## Money laundering

Recently in my country there were several campaigns to prevent people from giving out information on their debit card. The main reason was not the loss of money, but the responsibility in money laundering schemes.

Here is what would typically happen:

1. Someone steals, or even borrows your debit card and pin
2. They transfer illegally obtained funds to your account
3. They withdraw the money from your account

And of course, later the following happens:

4. The authorities track down the illegal transaction
5. The person whose debit card is used is held accountable for at least 100% of the withdrawn sum (even if they are not the ones who have withdrawn the money). And sometimes even penalties were dealt out.

Rules and regulations may be different where you live, but be aware that this could become a very unpleasant experience if you don't take immediate action.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to throw in one additional angle here, if somebody manages to steal enough information to fraudulently charge something on a credit card, *you have no real control over what they use the money for.* You're letting somebody not only use your money but leave a very clean paper trail that makes it look like you, personally, authorized the purchase.

Imagine trying to explain to the police at some point in the future why your credit card and your address was mixed in with a child porn ring or the purchase of explosive chemicals for a terrorist attack.